# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, desktop-application

I'm getting an exception that occurs in WindowsBase.dll when desktop switch event happens. I have an WPF application that sets the system events, and then run the other stuff on the different thread.

```cs
// SYSTEM EVENT WATCHER
_log.LogInformation("Setting session and desktop event watcher");
_systemEventWatcher.SessionSwitchEvent += SystemEventWatcher_SessionSwitchEvent;
_systemEventWatcher.SessionEndingEvent += SystemEventWatcher_SessionEndingEvent;
_systemEventWatcher.DesktopSwitchEvent += SystemEventWatcher_DesktopSwitchEvent;
_systemEventWatcher.SetSystemWatcher();

_ = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var manifestJson = await _manifestDownloader.DownloadManifestAsync();
    if (!await _moduleService.InitializeAsync(manifestJson))
    {
        TokenSource.Cancel();
    }
});
```

At this moment there is no UI involved. Once desktop switch happens for example pressing CTR - ALT - DEL. When event happens app just breaks producing **An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll** without even triggering event handler.

Interestingly, if I comment part where `Task.Run` is called, everything works as it should. If anyone have any ideas, why it is happening, would be interesting to know.

I have tried to run the code using `Thread.Start` method, but same thing happening. Don't really know what else to try.

Comment: Small changes might have big side-effects, this exception is normally raised when a garbage collection occurs.  Finding the code that corrupts the heap is paramount.

Comment: The root problem is likely elsewhere. System.ExecutionEngineException means something unspecified has happened in the CLR.  That happens but is often not detected until later.  Something gets corrupted and the error is only raise when the CLR tries to use that memory.  Do you use any Com interop, unmanaged or unsafe code? Docs say ExecutionEngineException  is now obsolete.

Comment: @Andy I do use it. One of the places that I use it is to set actual desktop switch event, there is some more, but at this point none of them should be called. Thanks for the response

Comment: I have some code detects when the user switches session. I just use Microsoft.Win32 SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;

Comment: I have event for session switch, but need one for desktop switch. interop is not my strong side, but looks like I have to do some research how to come up with better implementation.

Comment: Why do you execute async code on a background thread? Task.Run is redundant in the posted context. Even more, it's not advisable. Async methods already are non-blocking i.e. not synchronous (asynchronous). Wrapping them into Task.Run does not make them less non-blocking i.e. more asynchronous. Just remove Task.Run and simply await the async methods.

Comment: @BionicCode whether it makes sense, or not, but without it can't get it working. That call needs to run on the background thread.